# FFMPEG: watermark 4k Video failed

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm using FFMPEG to watermark my videos and it is working fine when the output is 1080p or lower even if the input is 4K

```
ffmpeg -i 4k.mkv -i watermark.png -filter_complex "scale=-2:1080,overlay=10:10" output1080.mp4
```

But if I tried to output a 4K video

```
ffmpeg -i 4k.mkv -i watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" output4k.mp4
```

I get this error message

```
    x264 [error]: malloc of size 26199520 failedme=00:00:00.88 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=1.72x
Video encoding failed
[aac @ 0xaa42240] Qavg: 17612.034
[aac @ 0xaa42240] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!
```

the linux I am working on is 32x so I'm using 32 version of ffmpeg

how can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe you hit the 3/4gb memory limit (of 32bit compiles)?

Comment: `malloc of size ...` failed. Looks like a memory problem.